# Which python rpc library works between 2.7 and 3.4

Tags: python, rpc

I am looking for a python rpc framework that I can intercommunicate between 2.7 and 3.4. I looked into RPyC and zerorpc but it stated in the documentation that it doesn't support this mode.

Any ideas for RPC/IPC between 2.7 and 3.4 versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XMLRPC standard library modules do a good job of hiding the underlying language and version.  Those modules appear in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, and both are already pre-installed in the standard library.

Here's a link to a nice worked-out example:  https://pymotw.com/2/SimpleXMLRPCServer/